# How to avoid xmlns attribute when creating XML element using vbscript?

Tags: xml, vbscript, xml-namespaces, xmldom

When adding a new element I see the `xmlns` attribute getting added with empty string. How can I avoid this? I have seen few answers but they are either in Java or .Net. Still tried those but they don't work. I need a solution for VBScript.

```vb
'load the xml file
Set objXMLDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")  
objXMLDoc.load(strFilePath)

'get all <MainError> nodes in the xml
Set mainNode = objXMLDoc.documentElement.SelectNodes("//MainError")

'get child nodes for the first <MainError> node
Set childNodes = mainNode(0).ChildNodes

Set objErrorNode = objXMLDoc.createElement("ChildError")
objErrorNode.text = "somevalue"
mainNode(0).appendChild(objErrorNode)
```

Output:

```xml
<MainError><ChildError xmlns="">somevalue</ChildError></MainError>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13229110/1630171) to a similar question you probably get the empty `xmlns` attribute because one of the parent elements is defined with a namespace, but you create the new child element without a namespace. Use `createNode` instead of `createElement` to create the child element with the same namespace as the ancestor node.

```vb
ns = "..."  '<-- define namespace string here according to whatever
            '    namespace is defined in your XML

Set objErrorNode = objXMLDoc.createNode(1, "ChildError", ns)
objErrorNode.text = "somevalue"
mainNode(0).appendChild(objErrorNode)
```