# Append xml file using vbscript

Tags: xml, vbscript

I am trying to append xml file using vb script. Below is the code I wrote:

```
Dim xmlDoc
Dim objRoot
Dim objRecord
Dim objFieldValue
Set xmlDoc = _
CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmlDoc.Async = "False"
xmlDoc.Load("C:\Temp\Scripts_products.xml")

Set objRoot = xmlDoc.documentElement

Set objRecord = _
xmlDoc.createElement("Features")
objRoot.appendChild objRecord

Set objFieldValue = _
xmlDoc.createElement("ComputerName")
objFieldValue.Text = "atl-ws-100"
objRecord.appendChild objFieldValue

Set objFieldValue = _
xmlDoc.createElement("AuditDate")
objFieldValue.Text = Date
objRecord.appendChild objFieldValue

xmlDoc.Save "C:\Temp\Scripts_products.xml"
```

Below is the output I am getting:

```
</Product>
<Features xmlns=""><ComputerName>atl-ws-100</ComputerName>      <AuditDate>1/19/2015</AuditDate></Features>
</Products>
```

How do I get of "" (Feature `xmlns` instead of Feature `xmlns=""`) which is coming in the feature tag.

Comment: It should be ... *what*?

Comment: That was a typo, sorry for that!                                                                                     Well, I just need <Feature xmlns>                                                                          Instead, I am getting <Features xmlns=""> So, how do I achieve desired output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid xmlns attribute when creating XML element using vbscript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26753606/1630171). You get this behavior when an ancestor node defines a (default) namespace.