# Powershell Remove Prefix from xml node

Tags: xml, powershell

So, I need to remove the prefix from a xml node.

```
    <Keys>
      <Key Name="Topic">Societies</Key>
      <METATRANSCRIPT:Key Name="Topic" Type="OpenVocabulary">Initiation</METATRANSCRIPT:Key>
      <Key Name="Keyword">Bondo</Key>
    </Keys>
```

The idea is is remove the METATRANSCRIPT: from the key node. This node was moved from another location inside xml.

```
    My code to get the node:
    $xml.Keys.Key | Where-Object{ $_.'#text' -ne $null}
```

How can i remove the prefix, on this single node?

Thanks a lot for any help

Comment: I looks to me like [Remove unwanted (empty) xmlns attribute added by appendChild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13220095/remove-unwanted-empty-xmlns-attribute-added-by-appendchild) has the information you need in some of the answers.

Comment: Thanks, @Andrew, i found the solution on that post.